# Colum Custom Datatables with Object Javascript or JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently using a CRUD made with NodeJS + MYSQL. I recently integrated my tables with Jquery Datatables Plugins, but I would like to add a custom column in which to return any information as a prefix in the ID.

example, a column of the type

```
ID | NAME | CPF | ACTIONS
01 | JAIR | 123 | IAMID01
```

I was reading something about object mapping but the maximum I got was that.

*db.js*

```
exports.execSQLQuery = (sqlQry, res) => {
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
port     : 3306,
user     : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'nodejs'
});

 connection.query(sqlQry, function(error, results, fields){
  if(error)
    res.json(error);
  else
  //*PASSAR RESULTADO PARA UMA VARIAVEL
  //var rows = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results[0]));
  res.json(results);
  connection.end();
  console.log('executou!');
  });
  };
```

*tabela.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $.get('/dados',function(dados){

// data is a JS object parsed from a JSON response
var ids = dados.map(elemento => elemento.ID);
console.log(ids)
$('#example').DataTable({

"ajax":{
  "url":"/dados",
  "dataSrc": ""
},
"columns":[
  { "data":"ID"},
  { "data":"Nome"},
  { "data":"CPF"},
  {
            data: null,
            className: "center",
            defaultContent: ids


   }
   ]

   });
   });
   });

     </script>
     </head>
      <body>
       <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Office2</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Office2</th>

        </tr>
      </tfoot>d
     </table>
     </body>
```

*clientesController.js*

```
 module.exports = {
 getDados : function(req,res){
   execSQLQuery('SELECT * FROM Clientes',res);

   },
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should alter your table and add the column as an self-incremental field.

```
ID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

After that every new record in your table will autogenerate a new id.

Comment: the ID is already defined so in theory I would need a new column that brings the value of the ID together with a prefix of type: Edit X (where X is the ID).